# How to post form fields to more than one text file

Tags: php, forms, post, text

I am working on a project where I need to submit a form with several fields to several text files.
so it would look something like this.

```
    <?php
$myfile = "data/sitetitle.txt";
if (isset($_POST['ta'])) {
    $newData = nl2br(htmlspecialchars($_POST['ta']));
    $handle = fopen($myfile, "w");
    fwrite($handle, $newData);
    fclose($handle);
}

if (file_exists($myfile)) {

    $myData = file_get_contents($myfile);
}
?>
<form action="admin.php" method="post">
<textarea class="inputs" name="ta" cols="64" rows="1">
    <?php echo str_replace("<br />","",$myData); ?>
</textarea>
<br /><br />
    <input class="myBtn" name="myBtn" type="submit" />
</form>
```

This works great but I can't get it to work on more than one field to seperate text files.

any help would be great
thanks in advance

paul

Comment: why not? `file_put_contents('file1.txt', $var1, FILE_APPEND); file_put_contents('file2.txt', $var2, FILE_APPEND); etc...`

Comment: thanks Marc but sorry v new to php, where would I put it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form action="admin.php" method="post"><input type="text" name="ta" ><input type="text" name="tb"><input type="text" name="tc"><input type="submit" name="myBtn" /></form>'
```

Thats the form.

This is the PHP:

```
$file1 = 'numerouno.txt';
$file2 = 'nummerto.txt';
$file3 = 'numberhree.txt';

$fild1 = $_POST['ta'];
$fild2 = $_POST['tb'];
$fild3 = $_POST['tc'];

file_put_contents($file1, $fild1, FILE_APPEND);
file_put_contents($file2, $fild2, FILE_APPEND);
file_put_contents($file3, $fild3, FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: Im sorry for that the codes are in one line. But I couldn't post my answer otherwise.

Comment: no problem but it is not the answer this will only save to one text file not 3?

Comment: Sorry, thought you wanted several into one text file. So you want several text fields into several textfiles with all the same text?

Comment: no there will be different things in the textfields like site tile, site keywords, site description etc etc

Comment: See my update answer, and ofc change the names to something more for you